# Adding protocol conformance to existing class then checking if implements?

Tags: swift, swift2, protocols, protocol-extension

I'm trying to group a couple of existing classes into a single custom protocol so I can treat them the same. For example, I'd like to group these two classes together under a single protocol like this:

```
protocol CLKComplicationTemplateRingable {
    var fillFraction: Float { get set }
}

extension CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingText: CLKComplicationTemplateRingable {

}

extension CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallRingText: CLKComplicationTemplateRingable {

}
```

How come when I do this, I cannot do this:

```
if let template as? CLKComplicationTemplateRingable {
    print("\(template.fillFraction)")
}
```

It doesn't compile, it gives this error: `Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer`

Am I approaching this correctly? Any advise or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
if template is CLKComplicationTemplateRingable {
    print("\(template.fillFraction)")
}
```

The "if let" variant would be:

```
if let template = template as? CLKComplicationTemplateRingable {
    print("\(template.fillFraction)")
}
```